# Error while trying save and retrieve images into database in android

Tags: android, database

I am new with android and I have an error on my app.

My app doing the following:

1- The user can choose to import an images from Camera or Gallery.

2- All the images are saved in database and the user can see all of them in list view 
on another activity.

While i click in menu bar icon to pass to another activity to see all the images
the app crashes and i get the following error in the log file :

```
11-06 15:16:17.199: E/AndroidRuntime(1789): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-06 15:16:17.199: E/AndroidRuntime(1789): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.demodbimage/com.example.demodbimage.ImagesList}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private static int FROM_CAMERA = 1;
    private static int FROM_GALLERY = 2;
    ImageView background;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        background = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgBackground);
       DataBaseHandler db = new DataBaseHandler(this);
     db.deleteAllContact();



    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);

        android.app.ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;

        }
        else if(id == R.id.action_camera) {

            showOptions();

            return true;
        }
        else if(id == R.id.action_view_as_list) {

            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ImagesList.class);
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    public void showOptions(){
        final String[] items = {"Camera","Gallery"};

        final int[] icons = {R.drawable.ic_camera,R.drawable.ic_gallery};


        ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( this, R.layout.list_item, items) {

            ViewHolder holder;

            class ViewHolder {
                ImageView icon;
                TextView title;
            }

            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


                if (convertView == null) {
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView .findViewById(R.id.icon);

                    holder.title = (TextView) convertView .findViewById(R.id.title);
                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                } else {
                    // view already defined, retrieve view holder
                    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }     

                holder.title.setText(items[position]);
                holder.icon.setImageResource(icons[position]);
                return convertView;
            }
        };


        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setTitle("Choose photo from:");
        builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if(which == 0){
                     Intent fromCamera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                     startActivityForResult(fromCamera, FROM_CAMERA);

                }
                else{
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    i.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(i, FROM_GALLERY);

                }



            }

        });

        builder.create();
        builder.show();
    }



    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == FROM_GALLERY && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);

                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();

                background.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
                insertToDatabase(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
        }
        else{
            if(requestCode == FROM_CAMERA  && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data )
            {

                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");
                background.setImageBitmap(photo);
                insertToDatabase(photo);

            }
        }
    }
    public  void insertToDatabase(Bitmap img){
            DataBaseHandler db = new DataBaseHandler(this);
            //db.deleteAllContact();
            // get image from drawable

            //Drawable i = background.getBackground();
            //Bitmap image = ((BitmapDrawable)i).getBitmap();
            //Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.id.imgBackground);

            // convert bitmap to byte
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            img.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            byte imageInByte[] = stream.toByteArray();

             //Inserting Contacts
            Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
            db.addContact(new Contact("Image", imageInByte));

    }



}
```

**DataBaseHandler.java**

```
public class DataBaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "imagedb";
    private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";

    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_IMAGE = "image";

    public DataBaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_IMAGE + " BLOB" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }


    // Adding new contact
    public void addContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, contact._name); // Contact Name
        values.put(KEY_IMAGE, contact._image); // Contact Phone

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }



    // Getting single contact
    Contact getContact(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                KEY_NAME, KEY_IMAGE }, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getString(1), cursor.getBlob(1));

        // return contact
        return contact;

    }


    // Getting All Contacts
    public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
        List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM contacts ORDER BY name";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Contact contact = new Contact();
                contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                contact.setImage(cursor.getBlob(2));
                // Adding contact to list
                contactList.add(contact);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        // close inserting data from database
        db.close();
        // return contact list
        return contactList;

    }

    // Updating single contact
    public int updateContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
        values.put(KEY_IMAGE, contact.getImage());

        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });

    }

    // Deleting single contact
    public void deleteContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
        db.close();
    }


    public void deleteAllContact() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS,null,null);
        db.close();
    }




    // Getting contacts Count
    public int getContactsCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();
    }
}
```

**ImagesList.java**

```
public class ImagesList extends Activity{

    ArrayList<Contact> imageArry = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    ContactImageAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.image_list);
        ListView dataList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);


        DataBaseHandler db = new DataBaseHandler(this);

        // Reading all contacts from database
        List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();

            for (Contact cn : contacts) {
                String log = "ID:" + cn.getID() + " Name: " + cn.getName()  + " ,Image: " + cn.getImage();

                // Writing Contacts to log
                Log.d("Result: ", log);
                //add contacts data in arrayList
                imageArry.add(cn);

            }

        adapter = new ContactImageAdapter(this,R.layout.layout_row,imageArry);
        dataList.setAdapter(adapter);

    }


}
```

**image_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**layout_row.xml** layout for each line in list view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"    
        android:src="@drawable/ic_gallery" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvImageName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:text="The name of the image"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I lost a lot of time for searching solution but didn't find.

Thanks in advenced!!!

**The full log file :**

```
11-06 15:16:17.199: E/AndroidRuntime(1789): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-06 15:16:17.199: E/AndroidRuntime(1789): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.demodbimage/com.example.demodbimage.ImagesList}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
11-06 15:16:17.199: E/AndroidRuntime(1789):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2351)
11-06 15:16:17.199: E/AndroidRuntime(1789):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
11-06 15:16:17.199: E/AndroidRuntime(1789):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:165)
11-06 15:16:17.199: E/AndroidRuntime(1789):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373)
11-06 15:16:17.199: E/AndroidRuntime(1789):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
11-06 15:16:17.199: E/AndroidRuntime(1789):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
11-06 15:16:17.199: E/AndroidRuntime(1789):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
11-06 15:16:17.199: E/AndroidRuntime(1789):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-06 15:16:17.199: E/AndroidRuntime(1789):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-06 15:16:17.199: E/AndroidRuntime(1789):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
11-06 15:16:17.199: E/AndroidRuntime(1789):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
11-06 15:16:17.199: E/AndroidRuntime(1789):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

*

Comment: Why would you save the images to the database if they're already on the device if you're not doing any manipulation on them? Why not just save the URI to the database and load the files to display in your listview?

Comment: I do it for practice working with database.

Comment: When i googling for the error in log file i see that is about a column that doesn't exists in the database, but i didn't understand it well.

Comment: Then you should probably post the error

Comment: "Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it"

Comment: Where is the error actually occurring? Your onActivityResult method at cursor.moveToFirst();?

Comment: I dont know maybe in "public  void insertToDatabase(Bitmap img)" on  MainActivity or on ImagesList.java in reading data.

Comment: The logs will tell you. Post the full logcat.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of just looking at the errors in logcat, look at the warnings. I believe you will see a warning that looks similar to the following:

```
WARN CursorWindow Window is full: requested allocation x bytes, free space x bytes, window size x bytes
```

This means that your cursor object is larger than the allocated size, which is normally 2Mb. Your cursor is loading a couple of image / blobs, which might cause it to grow larger than 2Mb.

### Solutions

1 - Read the images one by one. Instead of doing a query that selects everything e.g. SELECT * FROM contacts ... change it to read one or two images at a time by indexing the results. You can probably workout how much space you need by looking at the size of your images.

2 - Don't save the images in the database. It might be better to save the images in a directory on the SDcard and then just save the URI's into the db and read them into your cursor. then leave the decoding of the images to your application, which has much more memory to work with than your cursor object.

## Implementation of Solution 1


So I finally sat down and wrote the code and tested and it works great. So here is the code for solution 1. It works fine for me, obviously your implementation might be different depending on how you store and retrieve your data etc. So here goes

I have put in comments and modified the code so that it's easier to understand.

```
        //This is the part of my Sync method where I start pulling images from the database. 
        if(isSyncNeeded)
        {
            android.util.Log.w("     CURSOR FIXES     ", "BEGIN...");
            databaseHelperimages = new Handler_Database(Screen_Main.this);
            SQLiteDatabase dbimages = databaseHelperimages.getReadableDatabase();

            //I store my data in arraylists when I read the from the db.
            Session.arraylist_pictures_1 = new ArrayList<String>();
            Session.arraylist_pictures_2 = new ArrayList<String>();

            //Do all your reading here...
            // I have another query before this where I get the id of each row in my database. And here, I say, for each id in my database, get the corresponding image in that row.
            for (String id : Session.arraylist_allsubmissions_id)
            {
                Cursor c1 = dbimages.rawQuery("SELECT picture1 FROM submissions WHERE id" + " = " + id, null);
                if(c1.getCount() > 0) 
                {
                    if(c1.moveToFirst())
                    {
                        do
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                int index = c1.getColumnIndex("picture1");
                                String entry = c1.getString(index);
                                Session.arraylist_pictures_1.add(entry);
                            }
                            catch (IllegalStateException e)
                            {
                                //Do Nothing
                            }
                            catch (NullPointerException e)
                            {
                                //Do Nothing
                            }
                        }
                        while(c1.moveToNext());
                    }
                }
                c1.close();

                Cursor c2 = dbimages.rawQuery("SELECT picture2 FROM submissions WHERE id" + " = " + id, null);
                if(c2.getCount() > 0) 
                {
                    if(c2.moveToFirst())
                    {
                        do
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                int index = c2.getColumnIndex("picture2");
                                String entry = c2.getString(index);
                                Session.arraylist_pictures_2.add(entry);
                            }
                            catch (IllegalStateException e)
                            {
                                //Do Nothing
                            }
                            catch (NullPointerException e)
                            {
                                //Do Nothing
                            }
                        }
                        while(c2.moveToNext());
                    }
                }
                c2.close();

                //Continue doing this for all your images.
            }
            databaseHelperimages.close();
            dbimages.close();
            android.util.Log.w("     CURSOR FIXES     ", "END...");
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You can post an example of solution 1?

Comment: @user242201 , I can probably post a full example in a weeks time, since I have the same issue in a similar project and still need to implement it. However, you can just change your query to limit the results. Look at this thread on how to achieve this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/22067940/1518916 . Then just put that in a loop until all your images are loaded. So to sum up, you will limit your cursor results so that the size of the cursor is smaller, then save those results into a list or however you want, then recycle the cursor object and continue the process until all images are loaded.

Comment: @user242201 Please see my answer above, I have added the solution for part 1. I have done the code and it worked for me. Please let me know if it helps. Also, if you have questions, let me know. However, splitting the query into multiple parts / cursors did the trick for me. I was afraid that all cursor object share memory, but luckily they don't ! :)

Comment: First, thank you very much for posting your answer for me.  It took me for many hours but finally i solved my problem by myself last week. My app takes the images from camera, or gallery, and put it in Sqlite database. I think, saving images themself it's the good way for doing it, because - what if the images will delete from the phone and i tried it and it worked. I imported images to my app and delete all them in gallery in my phone and the they remain on my database.

Comment: If you have some time I can send you the zip folder of my proj and you will tell me your thoughts about that. just write you email adress, and again -  thanksssssssss!!! ;-)

Comment: @Josef, I am glad that it worked and you got everything sorted out. I too think that sometimes it is necessary to store it in the database. I have one app that is very security focused and as soon as a submission has been synced to our server, the data must be wiped from the device. If someone were to copy the image from the gallery and rename it, it will not get wiped etc... So sometimes it is necessary to save it in the db. My email is in my profile, and please vote for the question and answer so that it can help others :p

Comment: i cant find your email.